# Inserting ads within content

Tags: javascript, content, blog, adsense

I want to show `adsense ads` below the **4th** and **20th** paragraph of every blog post, ONLY if there is a **20th** paragraph.

I managed to insert an ad below the **4th** ad by placing the following code in my `functions.php` file, however I don't know how to add an additional ad after the **20th**.

```
// Insert ads after second paragraph of single post content.

add_filter( 'the_content', 'prefix_insert_post_ads' );

function prefix_insert_post_ads( $content ) {

    $ad_code = '<div style="float:left;padding: 15px;">
                      <script type="text/javascript">
                         google_ad_client = "ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
                         google_ad_slot = "xxxxxxxxxx";
                         google_ad_width = 300;
                         google_ad_height = 250;
                      </script>

                      <!-- Ad Name -->
                      <script type="text/javascript"
                         src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
                      </script>
                   </div>';

    if ( is_single() && ! is_admin() ) {
        return prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $ad_code, 3, $content );
    }

    return $content;
}

// Parent Function that makes the magic happen

function prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $insertion, $paragraph_id, $content ) {
    $closing_p = '</p>';

    $paragraphs = explode( $closing_p, $content );

    foreach ( $paragraphs as $index => $paragraph ) {

        if ( trim( $paragraph ) ) {
            $paragraphs[ $index ] .= $closing_p;
        }

        if ( $paragraph_id == $index + 1 ) {
            $paragraphs[ $index ] .= $insertion;
        }
    }

    return implode( '', $paragraphs );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have faith ;-)

Unfortunately, your code ain't correct in multiple ways. It assumes that the content only consists of content enclosed by paragraphs and doesn't work correctly if not.

This would be one solution:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'prefix_insert_post_ads');


/**
 * Content Filter 
 */
function prefix_insert_post_ads($content) {

    $insertion = 'Your AD Code';

    if (is_single() && ! is_admin()) {
        return prefix_insert_after_paragraphs($content, $insertion, array(4,20));
    }

    return $content;

}

// Function that makes the magic happen correctly

function prefix_insert_after_paragraphs($content, $insertion, $paragraph_indexes) {

    // find all paragraph ending offsets

    preg_match_all('#</p>#i', $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER+PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

    // reduce matches to offset positions

    $matches = array_map(function($match) {
        return $match[0][1] + 4; // return string offset + length of </p> Tag
    }, $matches);

    // reverse sort indexes: plain text insertion just works nicely in reverse order

    rsort($paragraph_indexes); 

    // cycle through and insert on demand

    foreach ($paragraph_indexes as $paragraph_index) {
        if ($paragraph_index <= count($matches)) {
            $offset_position = $matches[$paragraph_index-1];
            $content = substr($content, 0, $offset_position) . $insertion . substr($content, $offset_position);
        }
    }

    return $content;

}
```

Best regards from Salzburg!

Answer (score 0):

To properly count paragraphs, and to be consistant, the best will be is to make use of raw post content, and then apply the `wpautop` filter to the raw content. This way, WordPress will handle all the variables which at the end will determine how paragraphs are build and displayed

We can also look at a couple of other things to make this as reliable as possible

- Because this is only needed for a single post, we will make use of the queried object to get our raw post content from
- Make sure we have a minimum amount of paragraphs before inserting our adds
- Make use of the `in_the_loop()` condition to only target the main query loop
  -

I have decided to add all of this in a class

```
/** 
 * Class AdsINParagraphs
 * 
 * Class to inject ads into single post's content between paragraphs 
 * as required
 */
class GoogleAdsINParagraphs
{
     /** 
     * @var string $ad
     * @access protected
     * @since 1.1.0
     */
    protected $ad;

     /** 
     * @var int|string $min
     * @access protected
     * @since 1.1.0
     */
    protected $min;

     /** 
     * @var array $inject
     * @access protected
     * @since 1.1.0
     */
    protected $inject;

     /** 
     * @var $post = NULL
     * @access protected
     * @since 1.1.0
     */
    protected $post = NULL;

     /** 
     * @var $paragraphs = NULL
     * @access protected
     * @since 1.1.0
     */
    protected $paragraphs = NULL;

     /** 
     * @var $paraCount = 0
     * @access protected
     * @since 1.1.0
     */
    protected $paraCount = 0;

     /** 
     * @var $contentReplacement = NULL
     * @access protected
     * @since 1.1.0
     */
    protected $contentReplacement = NULL;

    /**
     * Public method __construct()
     *
     * Constructor for the GoogleAdsINParagraphs class
     *
     * @param string     $ad     The add that should be injected
     * @param string|int $min    The minimum amount of paragraphs that must exist
     * @param array      $inject An array of paragraph numbers where the add should be injected
     *                           If you need an ad before the content, simply pass 0 as first value
     * @access public
     * @since 1.1.0
     */
    public function __construct( $ad = NULL, $min = 4, $inject = [] )
    {
        $this->ad     = $ad;
        $this->min    = $min;
        $this->inject = $inject;
    }

    /**
     * Public method init()
     *
     * Initialize the 'the_content' filter callback
     *
     * @access public
     * @since 1.1.0
     */
    public function init()
    {
        add_filter( 'the_content', [$this, 'postContent'] );
    }

    /**
     * Protected method initHelperMethods()
     *
     * Initialize all the helper functions for the 'the_content' filter callback
     *
     * @access protected
     * @since 1.1.0
     */
    protected function initHelperMethods()
    {
        $this->post();
        $this->paragraphs();
        $this->paraCount();
        $this->contentReplacement();
    }


    /**
     * Protected method post()
     *
     * Gets the current post object and sanitize the post object. Sanitation 
     * is done as precaution should the query object being altered by some other
     * program/function/malicious code
     *
     * @access protected
     * @since 1.1.0
     */
    protected function post()
    {
        $post_raw   = get_queried_object();
        // Sanitize the post object in case that something externally changed the queried object
        $post       = sanitize_post( $post_raw );
        $this->post = $post;
    }

    /**
     * Protected method paragraphs()
     *
     * Gets the current post's post content, sanitizes it and then applies the wpautop filter
     * function to it to apply p tags to the raw content. After the filter function is applied,
     * the content is exploded into an array of paragraphs
     *
     * @access protected
     * @since 1.1.0
     */
    protected function paragraphs()
    {
        // Just in case, as extra precaution, run the raw post comment through wp_kses_post 
        $noEvilContent    = wp_kses_post( $this->post->post_content );
        $peedContent      = wpautop( $noEvilContent );
        $paragraphs       = explode( '<p>', $peedContent );

        $this->paragraphs = $paragraphs;
    }

    /**
     * Protected method paraCount()
     *
     * Counts the amount of paragraphs created by the paragraphs() method
     *
     * @access protected
     * @since 1.1.0
     */
    protected function paraCount()
    {
        $paraCount       = count( $this->paragraphs );

        $this->paraCount = (int) $paraCount;
    }

    /**
     * Protected method contentReplacement()
     *
     * This is where everything happens. The following checks are run
     * before ads are inserted into the content
     * - Check if there is at least the set minimum amount of paragraphs. 
     *   Checks are done against $this->min
     * - Check if there at least enough paragraphs to fullfil the lowest
     *   passed number in $this->inject
     * - Check to see if $this->inject is a valid array with values
     *
     * If all checks pass, ads is inserted into the content. If any value
     * in $this->inject is more than the amount of paragraphs, the ad is ignored
     * and not inserted
     *
     * @access protected
     * @since 1.1.0
     */
    protected function contentReplacement()
    {
        // Lets first run all our checks 

        $this->contentReplacement = $contentReplacement = NULL;

        // Make sure that we have at least more paragraphs than our minimum, bail if not
        if ( $this->paraCount < $this->min ) 
            return $this->contentReplacement;

        // Make sure that $this->inject is an array and not empty
        if (    !is_array( $this->inject ) 
             || !$this->inject
        )
            return $this->contentReplacement;

        /**
         * We will do the following checks and validation on $this->inject
         * - validate the array of ID's and remove negative numbers
         * - sort $this->inject array numerically ASC according to passed ID's 
         * - remove possible dublicates
         */
        $this->inject = filter_var( 
            $this->inject, 
            FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, 
            [
                'flags' => FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY,
                'options' => [
                    'min_range' => 0
                ]
            ]
        ); 
        asort( $this->inject );
        $this->inject = array_unique( $this->inject );

        // Make sure that we actaully have enough paragraphs to inject an add into 

        if ( $this->paraCount < $this->inject[0] )
            return $this->contentReplacement;

        // Now we can start to inject our ads into our content. Set $output as empty string
        $output = '';
        foreach ( $this->paragraphs as $key=>$paragraph ) {
            // Add ad in front of content if $this->inject[0] === 0
            if (    0 === $key 
                 && 0 === $this->inject[0]
            ) {
                $output .= '<p>' . $this->ad . '</p>' . $paragraph;
            } elseif ( !in_array( $key, $this->inject ) ) {
                $output .= $paragraph; 
            } else {
                $output .= $paragraph . '<p>' . $this->ad . '</p>';
            }
        } // endforeach

        $this->contentReplacement = $output;
    }

   /**
     * Public method postContent()
     *
     * This is the callback method for the 'the_content' filter. The content passed by reference
     * inside the filter is replaced by any valid value from $this->contentReplacement. This is done
     * purely for convenience
     *
     * @access public
     * @since 1.1.0
     * @return $content
     */
    public function postContent( $content )
    {
        // Lets first run our checks, make sure this is a single page and the main query
        if ( !is_single() )
            return $content;

        if ( !in_the_loop() )
            return $content;

        // Initialize our other helper methods. They should only run inside our condition
        $this->initHelperMethods();

        // Make sure $this->contentReplacement is not NULL, if so, just return $content
        if ( NULL === $this->contentReplacement )
            return $content;

        // We can now replace $content with $this->contentReplacement
        $content = $this->contentReplacement;

        return $content;
    }
} // end of class GoogleAdsINParagraphs
```

You can now use it as follow

```
$ad      = 'PLACE YOUR AD HERE';
$add_ads = new GoogleAdsINParagraphs( 
    $ad,     // Your ad which you want to add
    4,       // There should be at least 4 paragraphs
    [4, 20]  // Array of paragraph numbers after which you want to inject an add
);
$add_ads->init();
```